# display a different message depending if the user wants to remove an image, a user, a category or a news

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing an administrative panel where in all delete actions I show a modal asking if the user is sure that he wants to remove. And all my deletes are doing with jQuery Ajax.

If user click in "yes" I execute my delete, if user clicks in "no" I will close my modal.

The issue Im having is, in this administrative panel I can remove, news, users, categories and images.

But I just want to use one div dialog, like I have below:

```
<div class="delete_dialog">
    <div class="confirm">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this news?</p>
        <a href="#" id="delete">Yes</a>
        <a href="#" id="no">No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But If I use always this div, Im always getting this message "Are you sure you want to delete this news?".

Even when I click to delete an user or a categorie, Im showing a message if user wants to remove "this news".

Do you know how I can keep only one div, but display a different message depending on if user is removing an image, a news, an user or a category?

//This is my code jQuery, in case of a news delete

```
$('.content').on('click','.j_newsdel',function(){
    var newsid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.content .news li[id="'+ newsid +'"]').css('background','red');
    $('.delete_dialog').fadeIn("slow",function(){
        $('.confirm').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $("a#no").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.confirm').fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("slow"); 
        });
        $('.content .not li[id="'+ newsid +'"]').css('background','white');
    });
    $("a#delete").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post(url,{action:'news_del',id: newsid},function(){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('.content .news li[id="'+ newsid +'"]').fadeOut("slow");
        },500);
        $('.confirm').fadeOut("fast",function(){
            $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("fast"); 
        });
    });
});
return false;
})
```

Comment: you need to change the text of the p tag using `text()` function on every condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use data attributes to store the text displayed on delete and when user clicks on an element to remove it then you could replace the text message inside the dialog box using **.text()** and the data attribute value.